# How to make content inside bootstrap's container-fluid fit within remaining viewport and scroll everything else?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/WhTXWWl8EP

I can't seem force everything inside .container-fluid to scroll if it is overflowing viewportheight. Ideally .container-fluid would fill area below navigation, and if any child elements are overflowing then their overflow properly is used. Instead .container-fluid's height is increased

In the bootply example, panel-body should overflow with scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Since .panel-body is what is set to overflow: scroll, then you should be setting the height on that class.
I added the following to your CSS and it started scrolling the list.

```
.panel-body { height: 10vw; }
```

Comment: it would work if it was possible to set the height to 100vh-70px to compensate for navigation padding.

Comment: Hi jM2.me. You can do that like this.... `.panel-body{height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 70px);
  height: -moz-calc(100vh - 70px);
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);}`